# delphi как в Desing-Time изменить визуальный размер TComponent? (как это сделано в FMX?)

Tags: delphi, vcl

Когда я тяну мышь TComponent в режиме разработки рисуется окно нового размера но новый размер не устанавливается, т.к нет таких полей в TComponent  однако в FMX все контролы это не Vcl.TControl а `TFmxObject = class(TComponent, IFreeNotification, IActionClient)` и там можно изменять размер контрола в Desing-Time. Так какой интерфейс нужно поддерживать что бы в Vcl поменять размер TComponent.

Детальтей

Наследуюсь от TComponent и создаю в нем TCanvas
Parent будет в TComponent слать WM_PAINT
Региструю компонент в ide и добавляю на форму. Вижу нарисованный компонент внутри Parent но размер его изменить в режиме разработки не могу. Это легко можно сделать если унаследоватся от TControl но для моей задачи только TComponent как предок должен быть

Какой интерфейс нужно поддерживать что бы это стало возможно.
Вот например ide изменяет размер TControl вызывая
[5281B665]{vcldesigner260.bpl} VCLSurface.TControlItem.SetBoundsRect (Line 1183, "VCLSurface.pas" + 1)

VCLSurface.pas нигде нет что бы это посмотреть

Вот например как FmxObject Меняет размер

[4EE43175]{Package1.bpl} Unit3.TMemoTest.SetBounds (Line 45, "Unit3.pas" + 4) + $11
[101C0ACB]{fmxdesigner260.bpl} FmxSurface.TControlItem.SetBoundsRect (Line 1948, "FmxSurface.pas" + 1) + $56
[20FE441B]{designide260.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DoDragSize (Line 851, "Designer.pas" + 4) + $8
[20FE4B16]{designide260.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DragEnd (Line 991, "Designer.pas" + 22) + $3
[20FE7138]{designide260.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.MouseUp (Line 1776, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $2
[101CB397]{fmxdesigner260.bpl} FmxSurface.MouseEvent (Line 6792, "FmxSurface.pas" + 89) + $11
[101CB984]{fmxdesigner260.bpl} FmxSurface.TFmxDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 6951, "FmxSurface.pas" + 38) + $6
[07559E64]{fmx260.bpl  } FMX.Platform.Win.WndProc (Line 2286, "FMX.Platform.Win.pas" + 12) + $1

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBoRB.png]

Comment: У вас на картинке невизуальный компонент, поэтому непонятно о чем же вопрос? Конркетизируйте пожалуйста (кнопка "править")

Comment: Проверил на Delphi 10.4. TFmxObject также точно не меняет размеры в Desing-Time

Comment: Дело не в коде, а в том что вы хотите получить. Визуальные компоненты можно ресайзить. Невизуальные - нельзя. Ваше желание в чем состоит?

Comment: @Kromster что бы при отпуске мыши как на картинке размер изменился. в моем TMyComponent есть и высота и ширина и left top для  runtime сам могу а для design ваше не понимаю как сделать

Comment: Если это невизуальный компонент, его размер изменяться на должен и в рантайме он так же не должен быть виден. Если вы какими-то костылями это реализуете, то это будут костыли. Вопрос - зачем вы это делаете? Почему не сделать обычный визуальный компонент, если вам нужно поведение визуального компонента?